# Multiple image upload not working properly

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have a photo-sharing blog where registered users upload images. The images then go to the Admin Panel where I review them and they get published after my approval.

I want to enable multiple image upload i.e. the users must be able to select and upload multiple images.

I have tried putting the **multiple** attribute in the code. It has enabled the multiple images to be selected and uploaded BUT only one image is showing up in my Admin Panel for approval and all other images are discarded. How can I fix that?

Here is the code for the upload page:

```
<?php include ('header.php');?>

<?php @session_start();?>

<div class="domainSearchComplex">
<img src="theme_image/banner-mega.jpg" title="Change Image" style="width:960px; height:280px; margin-left:-55px !important;border-radius:15px;"> </div>

<?php //include ('slider.php');
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$type = $_SESSION['type']; 
$id_no = $_SESSION['id_no'];
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
$pic = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
{ $msg= "Error........Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"]; }
else
{
$pic = uniqid().$_FILES["image"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
"posts_images/" . $pic);


$query ="insert into `all_images` (`id_no`,`user_name`,`image`,`status`,`date`) values ('$id_no','$username' ,'$pic','9','$today')";

if(mysql_query($query))      
            {                   
                $msg = "<span style=\"color: green;margin-left:25px;margin-top:25px;\">Image Inserted Successfully...!</span>";
                }
        else        
        {$msg = "Error in insertion.........".mysql_error();    }
}}  
?>

<div style="height: 0;" class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="clearfix" id="mainContent">

<div class="clearfix" id="homeFeatured">

<?php include ('sidebar.php');?>

<div style="width: 66%; float: left;">
<h1 style="color:#DD003D; margin:39px 25px 17px 193px;">Post Your Images</h1>
<div class="tdp48 signupPart">

<div class="signUp" style="width:603px !important; height:400px !important; margin:0px 11px 17px 11px  !important; border-radius: 8px;">

<?php 
$qryc = "SELECT * FROM `register` where id_no='$id_no'";
$resc = mysql_query($qryc);
$rpc = mysql_fetch_array($resc);
$image = $rpc['image'];
?>

<form class="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data"  onsubmit="return validate();" method="post">
   <div class="loginTag" style="margin-top:-14px !important"><center>
    <br /><?php echo @$msg;?>

    <table style="margin-top:70px;">
        <tr>
            <td class="firstTd"><label>Image:</label></td>
            <td class="secondTd"><input name="image" multiple="" id="image" type="file" value="" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="INSERT" name="insert" class="btnSignup"  /></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</ul>
<!--</div>-->
</div> </div> </div> </div> </div>

<?php include ('footer.php');?>

<style>.menu2 {margin-top:4px !important;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function validate () {

var image = document.getElementById('image').value; 

if (image == '') {

    alert ('Please enter your image');
    return false;
    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a pretty big SQL injection problem here that you should fix first.

Use PDO with parameter binding - don't quote variables directly inside your sql statement

As for multiple images, it doesn't look like you're looping or doing anything to add multiple images in your code?

I would expect to see something along the lines of

```
foreach($images as $image){
  //insert image here
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i am not a pro at php or js. can you plz modify the code for me? it is such a pain in the ass to upload more than a hundred images one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Your input parameter definition is wrong for multiple image uploading. Try the following code instead:

```
<input name="image[]" multiple="multiple" id="image" type="file" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the multiple files with php then you need to make the `input` name value an array rather than a string by adding square brackets - i.e. `name="image[]"`.

So your image upload input would be:

```
<input name="image[]" multiple="" id="image" type="file" value="" />
```

This will make the `$_FILES` superglobal a multi-dimensional array containing the selected files.