# php renamming files to Array

Tags: php, function, loops, foreach

the following multiple upload code renames all the files (images) to something like 56c2ce2498220Array
*Please ignore all the mess in the code, i am not a pro.

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
$username = $_POST['user_name'];
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$pic = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
// Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
    }
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
        if ($_FILES['image']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $msg[] = "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $msg[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files
            $pic = uniqid().$_FILES["image"]["name"];
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $path . $pic));
        //if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
        // Number of successfully uploaded file
            $query ="insert into `all_tips` (`id_no`,`user_name`,`image`,`status`,`date`) values ('71','$username' ,'$pic','9','$today')";

if(mysql_query($query))      
            {                   
                $msg = "<span style=\"color: green;margin-left:25px;margin-top:25px;\">Image Inserted Successfully...!</span>";
                }
            else        
            {$msg = "Error in insertion.........".mysql_error();    }
        }}}}
?>
```

i want the files to be renamed something like this: 56c2c982de35djoinus2.jpg   i.e. uniqid PLUS their original name PLUS .format
i have tried a number of combinations but i can't get the right names.

Also, for reference: [Multiple image upload not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286249/multiple-image-upload-not-working-properly)

Comment: just a hint: it's the other way around - if you are a pro, you can have code like this because you rather know what is going on. if you ain't a pro you should have fine formatted code so you got a better chance to see what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, While uploading you are using:
`<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image">`

`[]` will submit in array form.
As you are already using foreach, So `$name` will have the value of file-name.

So, `$pic = uniqid().$name;` will work!